# Using Dependency Injection for classes instantiated at run time

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor

I have two classes: ImportBase.cs (Parent) and ImportFleet.cs (Child) which will in the future import a CSV file.  Each child of ImportBase will implement a different implementation of the actual import code.
The approriate child class to use is determined in a Service class where the correct class is instantiated and the import method called.  All is going well up until this point.

The problem is that I also want to Dependency Inject some repository classes into ImportBase and it's inherited classes (as I have attempted in the code below):

ImportBase.cs

```
namespace WebApi.Services.Import.Investments
{
    interface IImport
    {
        public void Import(IFormFile file, int UserId);
    }

    public abstract class ImportBase : IImport
    {
        public abstract void Import(IFormFile file, int UserId);

        protected List<InvestmentTransactionType> transactionTypes = new();

        protected IInvestmentEntityRepository _investmentEntityRepository;

        public ImportBase(IInvestmentEntityRepository investmentEntityRepository)
        {
            _investmentEntityRepository = investmentEntityRepository;
        }
    }
}
```

ImportFleet.cs

```
namespace WebApi.Services.Import.Investments
{
    public class ImportFleet : ImportBase
    {
        public ImportFleet(IInvestmentEntityRepository investmentEntityRepository) : base(investmentEntityRepository)
        {
        }

        public override void Import(IFormFile file, int UserId)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

InvestmentService.cs

```
namespace WebApi.Services
{
    public interface IInvestmentService
    {
        public void Import(IFormFile file, int UserId, int InvestmentEntityId);        
    }

    public class InvestmentService: IInvestmentService
    {

        public void Import(IFormFile file, int UserId, int InvestmentEntityId)
        {
            IImport importService = null;
            string investmentEntity = ImportBase.determineInvestmentEntityFromCsv(file);

            switch(investmentEntity)
            {
                case "fleet":
                    importService = new ImportFleet();   // problem is here
                    break;
            }

            if (importService != null)
            {
                importService.Import(file, UserId);
            }                          
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is the following line:

importService = new ImportKuflink();

Because I only determine which child class to instantiate at run time, I cannot take advantage of DI here.

Under normal circumstances I would make the Import classes a DI based service so all dependencies are available, however I have to create the instance at run time so this I don't think is possible.

Is there a way to accomplish the above?

Comment: I don't see any issue with creating the new instance at runtime, but this looks like it would benefit from using a Factory Pattern. Maybe have a `ImportServiceFactory` return the new instance. This factory can be dependency injected.

Comment: @thewallrus when  using a Factory class I still have the same issue when attempting to create the instance of the child class.  It is expecting the services I want injected as parameters when calling new()

Comment: Injecting services as parameters (through constructor) is default behavior in .NET DI system. And the services can depend on each other. You have to register the services with the correct scope on startup. We would need to see your startup or program.cs to see how the services are being registered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simplified version of your code that demonstrates how you can populate an instance of an object from a DI service container.

In your `InvestmentService`:

1. Inject the `IServiceProvider`.
2. Use the little known utility `ActivatorUtilities` to get a fully DI'd instance of your object.
3. Make sure you dispose it properly if it implemenents `IDisposable`.  I've included an async version if you use anything that needs a `IAsyncDisposable`.

```cs
public class InvestmentService : IInvestmentService
{
    private IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public InvestmentService(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        //...
    }

    public Import()
    {
        IImport? importService = null;
        IDisposable? disposable = null;

        var importFleet = ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<ImportFleet>(_serviceProvider);
        if (importFleet is IDisposable)
            disposable = importFleet as IDisposable;

        importService = importFleet as IImport;
        // Do whatever you want to do with it

        disposable?.Dispose();
    }

    public async ValueTask ImportAsync()
    {
        IImport? importService = null;
        IDisposable? disposable = null;
        IAsyncDisposable? asyncDisposable = null;

        var importFleet = ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<ImportFleet>(_serviceProvider);

        if (importFleet is IDisposable)
            disposable = importFleet as IDisposable;

        if (importFleet is IAsyncDisposable)
            asyncDisposable = importFleet as IAsyncDisposable;

        importService = importFleet as IImport;
        // Do whatever you want to do with it

        disposable?.Dispose();

        if (asyncDisposable is not null)
            await asyncDisposable.DisposeAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: this works great, the correct class can be instantiated along with any DIs and used in a general context - You have provided an extremely useful piece of code.  How important is the disposability? as I can see the code would be much cleaner without it.

Comment: Important.  If you don't dispose objects that implement `IDisposable` you will get memory leaks in your application.  However, you only need to implement it if your classes implement it.

Comment: thanks.  Curious to as why a separate disposable object is required to dispose importFleet.  Is there no method available on importFleet which could dispose of it (considering it implements IDisposable) ?

Comment: You aren't disposing importFleet, you're disposing `importService` which is an `IImport` instance.  It doesn't implement `IDisposable`. So you capture whichever object you create as `disposable` if it needs disposing and then just call `Dispose` on it at the end (if it's not null - `disposable?`).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course there is a way to accomplish this. But I guess the DI container you are using (like from MS) won't help you here.

I've been fiddling with crap like this for like two years so far and still am busy with it. Two years of creating my own IoC framework.

Usual DI/IoC microkernels follow OCP and other really mandatory concepts and patterns. What I've done is leaving one single small door open. I won't bore you with details. The fundamental idea is that a class must be decorated with the appropriate attributes in code, and then is able to call the microkernel within its constructor (which has been called by a simple "var foo = new Barney();") to let an entity be modified like it had been created by the microkernel.

There is no(t yet a) way to hook into the plain new() code. Some cheer this, some don't. I'm with the cheerleaders here. Why? Side-effects.

Imagine this:

```
public class SomeNumber
{
    public int SomeValue { get; private set; }

    public SomeNumber()
    {
        SomeValue = 19;
    }
}
```

Okay? Let's assume you'd modified the new() process by whatever, then another user of your code goes:

```
Assert.AreEqual(19, someNumberEntity.SomeNumber);
```

and this code throws an exception, because for whatever reason your modifying code set the number to 7.

Now look at this code (from a unit test):

```
using System.Reflection;
using Kis.Core.Attributes;

namespace UnitTests_Kis.Core
{
    [KisAware]
    public class KisAwareSimpleClass
    {
        [Property(value: 123)]
        public int ValueToCheck { get; set; } = 0;

        [Property(value: "I am the doctor!")]
        public string Name { get; set; } = "";

        public KisAwareSimpleClass()
        {
            var t = this.GetType();
            var fqtn = t.FullName;
            var ec = new Kis.Core.EntityCreator(Assembly.GetAssembly(t));
            ec.ModifyExistingEntity(fullyQualifiedTypeName: fqtn, existingEntity: this);
        }
    }
}
```

Clean code isn't always easily readable, but the aspects/attributes will raise coder's awareness.

PS: I posted the unit test code on purpose to show you what's happening.

Short version:

```
Microkernel.Modify(this);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can inject a factory which has the services injected into it.

```
public interface IImportFactory
{
    ImportFleet CreateFleetImporter();
}

public class MyImportFactory : IImportFactory
{
    private readonly IMyDependency1 _dependency1;
    private readonly IMyDependency2 _dependency2;  

    public MyImportFactory(IMyDependency1 dependency1, IMyDependency2 dependency2)
    {
        _dependency1 = dependency1;
        _dependency2 = dependency2;
    }

    public ImportFleet CreateFleetImporter()
    {
        return new ImportFleet(_dependency1, _dependency2);
    }
}
```

Then inject the factory as a dependency in your Service class.